# Can't find the "Default" tab usually located next to "Compositing"

Tags: rendering

I am a new user of blender. I want to know how to find the "Default" tab usually located next to "Compositing". I cannot seem to find it. Thank you.

(I am using Blender 2.8)

Have a great day.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You don’t really need it. Maybe you deleted it by mistake. Just rearrange your panels the way you want. The *tabs* are there just to save time with rearranging panels, you don't lose any functionality if you delete a tab :).

Comment: However, if you really really want it, just open a new Blender document, and it will be there :).

Comment: Thank you. It was required for me to use it as I was inserting something. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Yes. It is the tab you always start with, and if you really think you need it, then you can restart Blender.

Comment: I would suggest watching an absolute basics(Navigation and changes most 2.7 tutorials still work with 2.8 just somethings moved around ) video.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Blender community :)

You can use the 'Layout' view as default. The things that changes is that are shown by default some tools focusing on each type of work you will be doing. For me, 80% of my time I use in the 'Layout' tab. Script and Sculpting are for more specific works. But if you feel lost you can go over this '+' icon right next to the other tabs and add the tab you are looking for. Hope it helps 
[image]

[image]